# Get the public URL from the browser URL in LinkedIn API

Tags: api, linkedin-api

How can I get the public URL from the browser URL? By "browser URL" I mean something like:

http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=34661816&pid=5000742&authType=name&authToken=j2C6&trk=pbmap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't fetch the public profile URL using the "browser URL". Via the LinkedIn API, you can fetch a user's public profile url with the following API call:

GET http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(public-profile-url)

Note that I'm passing in the "public-profile-url" as a field selector. This is also assuming that you've properly authenticated your application as well: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I searched around and found out that indeed, there is no way to get the info using that type of URL.

Comment: @Kamyar Thanks for the solution. I was struggling to get email_address and profile_url. You suggestion solved it. But, could you please direct  me to the docs where it is mentioned to use like this? Thanks in advance.